# Invoke giphy search in slack nestor bot reply

Tags: javascript, bots, slack, giphy

The giphy plugin is in use in a Slack channel, would it be possible for the nestor bot reply to have a giphy search invoked by something like `msg.reply('/giphy ' + text, done);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out they are not allowed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966648/how-can-i-make-it-so-that-slack-bots-can-use-giphy). 
I made a way around by using the [superagent npm for ajax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) and the [giphy api](https://api.giphy.com/) in my slackbot file like this:

```
  var url = 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=' + 'searchString' + '&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&rating=r';
  request.get(url).end( function(err, res) {
    // console.log(res.body.data)
    bot.reply(message, 'giphy for you ' +  searchString + giph);
});
```

Hope this helps